# Updating two level sub-document which is list in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a hotel collection whose one of the document looks like this -

```
{
    "_id" : "HOTEL_1",
    "name" : "Decent hotel",
    "chainId" : "CHN123",
    "rooms" : [
        {
            "id" : "ROM1",
            "name" : "decent rooms",
            "ratePlans" : [
                {
                    "ratePlanId" : "RPNB1191989873C2G",
                    "status" : "INACTIVE",
                    "marginPart" : {
                        "marginType" : "PERCENTAGE",
                        "margin" : "32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ratePlanId" : "RPNE0992HBG6I0GE8",
                    "status" : "INACTIVE",
                    "marginPart" : {
                        "marginType" : "PERCENTAGE",
                        "margin" : "32"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "ROM2",
            "name" : "another decent rooms"
            "ratePlans" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update status as ACTIVE of all the rate plans of all the rooms with a certain condition like chainId.

I tried with this but failed -

```
db.hotel.updateMany({ "chainId" : "CHN_123"},{$set : {"rooms.$ratePlans.$status" : "ACTIVE" }});
```

I also want to update margin as common value say 50% to all such rates.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updateMany try the below query

```
db.hotel.update({ "chainId" : "CHN_123"},{$set : {"rooms.$ratePlans.$status" : "ACTIVE" }},{multi:true,upsert:false},function(err,doc){
      console.log(doc)
});
```

It works always!!

Comment: Got this Error: Fourth argument must be empty when specifying upsert and multi with an object.

Comment: You are using terminal I guess, so try 
db.hotel.update({ "chainId" : "CHN_123"},{$set : {"rooms.$ratePlans.$status" : "ACTIVE" }},{multi:true,upsert:false})

Comment: still no luck - `cannot use the part (rooms of rooms.$ratePlans.$status) to traverse the element` this is the same error I encountered previously.